# Apache Proxy with authentication

Tags: php, apache, authentication, proxy

I run Chronos which is running in 4040 port.
I want to set proxy in apache to access the Chronos, but I want to allow access with authentication.

I found Proxy with Basic auth in below article, but I have to auth with LDAP so below can't work for me.
[Setting up an Apache Proxy with Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724599/setting-up-an-apache-proxy-with-authentication)

Is there way to custom auth with proxy ? 
FYI, I installed PHP so PHP thing is work for me.

Thanks
Ducheol